# Put part of setting in another file

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this setting for sending email

```
 EXTENSIONS = {
     'shop.mail3.StatusMailer': 500    
 }

 STATUSMAILER_RECIPIENTS = ['']
 MAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
 MAIL_PORT = 587
 MAIL_USER = ' '
 MAIL_PASS = ' '
```

And I put this part in another file called `settings_mail.py`  (because in my project many spiders has this part)
AND use `import  settings_mail`
But it didn't work.

I want to know is there any method to acheive it.
Please guide me a bit Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import every setting from `settings_mail.py` into the scope of `settings`. Put this at the end of `settings.py`:

```
from settings_mail import *
```